# 2006 Ford Focus always shows battery light after driving for 5 minutes

Tags: ford, battery, focus, charging

I have a 2006 Ford Focus. I got new battery and a new alternator two months ago. But it just started showing the battery light on dashboard few days back. The battery light shows always after about 5 minutes of driving and stays for about 2 minutes then goes away. Shows back again after few minutes and goes away. Then it doesn't show it again on during the entire trip. Please help me figure out this weird problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Put a multimeter on the battery and check the voltage output of the alternator both when the light is off and on. This should tell you what is happening to turn the light on in the first place. It could either be under or over charging. Also, just because it's a new alternator, doesn't mean there isn't an issue with it.